# How do I do assert an element using begins / starts with in Playwright

Tags: e2e-testing, playwright, playwright-test

I can't find any available [assertion](https://playwright.dev/docs/test-assertions#non-retrying-assertions) for Playwright using `startsWith` or `BeginsWith` similar to jest.

I do it with something like below:

```js
const guidSample = '1y2x3z';
const startsWithGuid = guidSample.startsWith('1y');
expect(startsWithGuid).toEqual(true);
```

However, its usually flaky. Would there be a simpler way to use this using regex maybe with a combination of `expect(value).toEqual()` or `expect(value).toMatch()`?

Comment: Can you provide more context? Usually in Playwright, you're not asserting on raw strings, you're asserting on element text contents or attributes. If you're pulling string data from an element, then asserting it like this, it could be breaking the [web first assertion](https://playwright.dev/docs/best-practices#use-web-first-assertions) pattern. That said, `.toMatch(/^1y/)` should work fine for replacing `startsWith`, although be careful for special regex characters. [Related GH issue](https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/27663).

Comment: This works. It's a long explanation but I just need to check that it generates the correct ID format - its an Ethereum address that usually starts with. We had instances where it generates a Bitcoin address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check the text from the element you can use following assertion:

```js
await expect(page.locator('.your-element-selector')).toHaveText(/^1y/);
```

or from your example it may be:

```js
const guidSample = '1y2x3z';
expect(guidSample).toMatch(/^1y/);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could create custom expect matcher for playwright.

Official doc: https://playwright.dev/docs/test-assertions#add-custom-matchers-using-expectextend

In your case i have created simple usage for `expect().toStartsWith()`
as for passing `string` or `locator`

Creating custom expect:

```js
export const expect = baseExpect.extend({
    async toStartsWith(matcher: string | Locator, expected: string, options?: { timeout?: number }) {
        const assertionName = 'toStartsWith';
        let pass: boolean;
        let matcherResult: any;

        if (typeof matcher == 'string') {
            pass = matcher.startsWith(expected);
            matcherResult = {actual: matcher};
        } else {
            try {
                const text = await matcher.innerText({timeout: options?.timeout ?? 10_000});
                pass = text.startsWith(expected);
                matcherResult = {actual: text};
            } catch (e: any) {
                matcherResult = {actual: e.message};
                pass = false;
            }

        }

        const message = () => this.utils.matcherHint(assertionName, undefined, undefined, {isNot: this.isNot}) +
            '\n\n' +
            `Expected: ${this.isNot ? 'not' : ''}${this.utils.printExpected(expected)}\n\n` +
            (matcherResult ? `Received: ${this.utils.printReceived(matcherResult.actual)}` : '');

        return {
            message,
            pass,
            name: assertionName,
            expected,
            actual: matcherResult?.actual,
        };
    },
});
```

And example test:

```js
// navigate to page
await page.goto('https://playwright.dev');

// string expect
await expect('abc fgh').toStartsWith('abc');

// locator expect
const getStartedElement: Locator = page.locator('header .container a[class*=\'getStarted\']');
await expect(getStartedElement).toStartsWith('GET');
```

**Don't forget to import expect from the the file that you extend default one.**